# Parent - Car. Sub-class: Electric or Fossil. Child: Private car or Taxi

Tags: java

I'm recently picking up OOP, and this has me very confused. 
I want to make a super class Car and Electric or Fossil cars as its subclasses.

```
`abstract class Electric extends Car`.
```

The issue is that I only want to make instances of either Private or Taxi. How can I structure this, so that I would ideally be allowed to make a statement as

```
Taxi cab1 = new Fossil()
```

I realize this is a question with an obvious answer, but after looking at generics and interfaces until my eyes got sore, the frustration has been growing.

I would greatly appreciate if somebody could remind me how this can be done, as I'm positive I have known and since forgot.

Comment: Before drawing up your class hierarchy, also clarify what you want these objects to *do*, because that'll determine what could make sense as an interface or abstract class, and what their relation should be.

For example, does Taxi have different methods than Private?

Comment: Good point. Private and Taxi will have a few methods they do not share, and an electric taxi will need to inherit all methods from Electric, and then Car. A taxi can also be Fossil, in which case it will need to inherit all Fossil methods, and none of the Electric methods. The common methods for Electric and Fossil will be found in Car.

Comment: You may want to break out the engine type into a separate class and use it to compose custom types, e.g. `Taxi cab1 = new Taxi(new ElectricMotor());`.

Comment: Indeed, the "component" pattern would make a lot of sense there

Comment: Also note that: You won't ever be able to do "Taxi cab1 = new Fossil()" because that'd require that you can cast Fossil into Taxi. But not every fossil car is a taxi!

Comment: Oh - that's exactly what I have been trying to do, but clearly you are correct. Which - I assume - means I will have to structure this differently. At least this puts the issue to rest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking something like this?

***Car Class:***

```
public class Car{

private int yearOfManufacture;
private String brand;
private String model;
private Engine engine;  

public Car(String pBrand, String pModel, int pYearOfManufacture, Engine pEngine){
    this.yearOfManufacture = pYearOfManufacture;
    this.brand = pBrand;
    this.model = pModel;
    this.engine = pEngine;
}

}
```

***Engine Class:***

```
public class Engine {

 private int power;
 private int emission;

 public Engine(int power, int emission) {
  this.power = power;
  this.emission = emission;
 }
}
```

***IC Engine Class:***

```
public class ICEngine extends Engine {

 private int numOfValves;

 public ICEngine(int power, int emission, int numOfValves) {
  super(int power, int emission);
  this.numOfValves = numOfValves;
 }
}
```

***Electric Engine Class:***

```
public class ElectricEngine extends Engine {

 private int wattage;

 public ICEngine(int power, int emission, int wattage) {
  super(int power, int emission);
  this.wattage = wattage;
 }
}
```

***Taxi Class:***

```
public class Taxi extends Car{

    private String driverName;

    public Taxi(String driverName, String pBrand, String pModel, int pYearOfManufacture, Engine engine){
        super(pBrand, pModel, pYearOfManufacture, engine);
        this.driverName = driverName;
    }
}
```

***Private Car Class:***

```
public class PrivateCar extends Car {

 private String ownerName;

 public PrivateCar(String ownerName, String pBrand, String pModel, int pYearOfManufacture, Engine engine) {
  super(pBrand, pModel, pYearOfManufacture, engine);
  this.ownerName = ownerName;
 }


}
```

***Consuming Application Class:***

```
public class MyApp {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Engine eEngine1 = new ElectricEngine(100, 10, 10000);
  Car myElectricTaxi = new Taxi("Driver1", "Honda", "Accord", 2013, eEngine1);

  Engine icEngine1 = new ICEngine(100, 10, 6);
  Car myICTaxi = new Taxi("Driver2", "Honda", "Accord", 2013, icEngine1);

  Engine eEngine2 = new ElectricEngine(100, 10, 10000);
  Car myElectricPrivateCar = new PrivateCar("Owner1", "Honda", "Accord", 2013, eEngine2);

  Engine icEngine2 = new ICEngine(100, 10, 4);
  Car myICPrivateCar = new PrivateCar("Owner2", "Honda", "Accord", 2013, icEngine2);

 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

***Car Class:***

```
public class Car{

private int yearOfManufacture;
private String brand;
private String model;

private boolean forRent;


public Car(String pBrand, String pModel, int pYearOfManufacture, boolean pForRent){
    this.yearOfManufacture = pYearOfManufacture;
    this.brand = pBrand;
    this.model = pModel;
    this.forRent = pForRent;
}


public boolean isPrivate(){
    return (!forRent);
}

public int getYear()                
    {
        return this.yearOfManufacture;
    }

public String getBrand()
    {
        return this.brand;
    }

public void setYear(int year)
    {
        this.yearOfManufacture = year;
    }

public void setBrand(String carBrand)
    {
        this.brand = carBrand;
    }

public void setModel(String model)                        
    {
        this.model = model;   

public String getModel()
    {
        return this.model;
    }

}
```

***Electric Car Class:***

```
public class ElectricCar extends Car{

    private int electricPowerOutput;

    public ElectricCar(String pBrand, String pModel, int pYearOfManufacture, int pElectricPowerOutput, boolean pForRent){
        super(pBrand,pModel,pYearOfManufacture,pForRent);
        this.electricPowerOutput = pElectricPowerOutput;
    }

    public int getElectricPowerOutput(){
        return this.electricPowerOutput;
    }

    public void setElectricPowerOutput(int electricPower){
        this.electricPowerOutput = electricPower;
    }

}
```

***Fossil Car:***

```
public class FossilCar extends Car{

    private int emissionRating;

    public ElectricCar(String pBrand, String pModel, int pYearOfManufacture, int pEmissionRating, boolean pForRent){
        super(pBrand,pModel,pYearOfManufacture,pForRent);
        this.emissionRating = pEmissionRating;
    }

    public int getEmissionRating(){
        return this.emissionRating;
    }

    public void setElectricPowerOutput(int emissionRating){
        this.emissionRating = emissionRating;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the effort. This is though not the issue itself. The problem I had was trying to typecast a Taxi into a Fossil which extends Car.